# How to sort an array by a custom structure

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**Sorry - really bad title but couldn't figure how else to put it!**

I am creating an array of a folder structure like this:

Each entry in the table has three fields:

```
| parent id | route | label      |
|-----------|-------|------------|
| 1         |       | account    |
| 2         | 1     | section 1  |
| 3         | 1     | section 2  |
| 4         | 1/2   | s1 options |
| 5         | 1/3   | s2 options |
| 6         | 1/2/4 | settings   |
| 7         | 1/3/5 | language   |
```

This would look like this:

```
account / 
account / section 1 / 
account / section 2 / 
account / section 1 / s1 options / 
account / section 2 / s2 options / 
account / section 1 / s1 options / settings
account / section 2 / s2 options / language
```

To create this the `route` is parsed using the `parent id` and its `label`. All straightforward so far.

As I'm sure you'll appreciate, I want to list it as:

```
account / 
account / section 1 / 
account / section 1 / s1 options / 
account / section 1 / s1 options / settings
account / section 2 / 
account / section 2 / s2 options / 
account / section 2 / s2 options / language
```

This is where I'm having problems! I've tried different sort options both in the sql query and various array options but I'm getting stuck.

I have a page where a user can create new folders by selecting the parent folder first and then adding in the new folder name, so I don't have control over how the folder structure is built or in what order.

At the moment I'm trying to avoid anything too long and complex because I'm sure there must be a way of doing it simply...I just can't find it.

Suggestions/solutions valued! :)

SQL -

```
$q1 = $dbp->prepare("SELECT * FROM `structure`");
$q1->execute();
while ($d1 = $q1->fetch()) {
    $structure_parent[] = $d1['parent'];
    $structure_route[] = $d1['route'];
    $structure_label[] = $d1['label'];
    $structure[$d1['parent']] = $d1['label'];
}
```

SELECT -

```
<select id="parent" name="parent">
<?php
$p = 0;
while($p < count($structure_parent)) {
    // build route map
    $route = explode("/", $structure_route[$p]);
    $s = 0;
    while($s < count($route)) {
        $route_mapping[] = $structure[$route[$s]];
        $s++;
    }
    if($structure_route[$p] > "") $routemap = implode(" / ", $route_mapping)." / ";
    else $routemap = "";
    unset($route_mapping);
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $structure_parent[$p]; ?>"><?php echo " / ".$routemap.$structure_label[$p]; ?></option>
    <?php
    $p++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: It would have been useful to see the query that you are currently using.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sql and select added. Not sure it deserved a downvote though?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry. For some reason I was telling myself it was irrelevant because it wasn't really doing anything helpful towards the solution! My bad :)

Comment: Once you've built your array, you can sort it using a custom call-back to `usort` / `uasort`, similar to the multi-dimensional array example in the linked duplicate. You just need to define a function that, given two entries, says which should come first in the final list.

Comment: @IMSoP So, out of the vast 'array' of answers (pun intended!), which would you have chosen? TBH I don't think this should have been marked as a duplicate to that one.

Comment: @StephenWeatherill Look at the one headed "Sorting by multiple fields". In your case, the "fields" are the parts separated by '/'.

Comment: @IMSoP OK, thank you. Will look at that in more depth when I have the space for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply using `array_combine` and `array_column` to create label map and `strtr` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)) to swap the route.

Consider the following example (I skip the DB extraction and just init array with the data):

```
$arr = [];
$arr[] = array("id" => 1, "route" => "", "label" => "account");
$arr[] = array("id" => 2, "route" => "1", "label" => "section 1");
$arr[] = array("id" => 3, "route" => "1", "label" => "section 2");
$arr[] = array("id" => 4, "route" => "1/2", "label" => "s1 options");
$arr[] = array("id" => 5, "route" => "1/3", "label" => "s2 options");
$arr[] = array("id" => 6, "route" => "1/2/4", "label" => "settings");
$arr[] = array("id" => 7, "route" => "1/3/5", "label" => "language");

$labels = array_combine(array_column($arr, "id"), array_column($arr, "label")); // labels will be mapping between id to label
foreach($arr as $e) {
    $ans[] = strtr($e["route"], $labels) . "/" . $e["label"]; //build path according to route and add your label
}
sort($ans);
```

Now `$ans` will have you desire output.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this gives me the same as I have to start with, not the desired order. I did a direct copy/paste to see it working first. :(

Comment: In my query above I show the output twice. The first one is what I currently get, but the second one show the desired output. In your answer it shows the output in the same order as the array but it needs to be sorted more logically. I hope that makes more sense. :)

Comment: @StephenWeatherill I was missing `sort($ans);` - updated my answer -please check the order now

Comment: AWESOME - does the trick. Thank you! I'm now just trying to work out how to keep the original `id` because it seems to get lost somewhere. I did a quick test by adding it onto the end and then splitting the result into key/value but it does something a bit strange! I need it for the <option> value so that it properly references it. For reference, the new order created is 1,2,3,5,4,6 and I need to keep that for the option value.

Comment: @StephenWeatherill I would insert the path to `$ans` by id as key so you can get the key then you loop on the array. If this post helped you may mark it as accepted

Comment: It does now - thank you! :)